# How to open a repository creating it if it does not exist in JGit?

Tags: jgit

Came up with:

```java
/**
 * Create a repo at the specified directory or open one if it already
 * exists. Return a {@link Git} object...
 *
 * @param p
 *            Path to the repo root (the dir that contains the .git folder)
 * @return a "Git" object to run porcelain commands on...
 * @throws GitterException
 *             if the specified path cannot be resolved to a directory, or
 *             the repository failed to be build (...) or created
 */
public static Git open(Path p) throws GitterException {
    if (!Files.isDirectory(p)) // default LinkOption is follow links
        throw new GitterException(p + " can't be resolved to a directory");
    Repository localRepo = null;
    try {
        localRepo = new FileRepository(Paths.get(p.toString(), ".git")
            .toFile()); // do I have to specify the .git folder ?
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new GitterException("Failed to build Repository instance", e);
    }
    try {
        localRepo.create();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // ISE when the repo exists !
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new GitterException("Failed to create Repository instance", e);
    }
    return new Git(localRepo);
}
```

Am I missing something obvious ? Is it as complicated as this ?

Run across setMustExist(boolean) in the [BaseRepositoryBuilder](http://resources.codemaps.org/genertedJavadocs/JGit/eAII189zyc4W/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/BaseRepositoryBuilder.html) could it be used ?

Comment: AFAIK there it doesn't get much shorter. You could replace the try-catch part that determines if the repository exists with a RepositoryBuilder like so: `RepositoryBuilder builder new FileRepositoryBuilder(); builder.findGitDir( path );`. Afterwards you can test with `builder.getGitDir() != null` if the path points to an existing repository.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann: should be oneliner - but then why have Git _and_ _Repository_ classes ? Dunno - anyway you may wish to post your comment as an answer - maybe editing my method with your code. Also what happens if I finally close() the local repository inside open() ? Would `Git` returned instance still be valid ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortest solution I could find is to always call `create()` and ignore the *already exists* exception.

```java
static Git openOrCreate(File gitDirectory) throws IOException {
  Repository repository = new FileRepository(gitDirectory);
  try {
    repository.create();
  } catch(IllegalStateException repositoryExists) {
  }
  return new Git(repository);
}
```

The code has its caveats though. The `IllegalStateException` seems to be an implementation detail that might change and break the above code. In addition, `FileRepository` resides in an internal package and is not part of the public JGit API.

The following is a solution that avoids these problems:

```java
static Git openOrCreate(File gitDirectory) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
  Git git;
  FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
  repositoryBuilder.addCeilingDirectory(gitDirectory);
  repositoryBuilder.findGitDir(gitDirectory);
  if( repositoryBuilder.getGitDir() == null ) {
    git = Git.init().setDirectory(gitDirectory.getParentFile()).call();
  } else {
    git = new Git(repositoryBuilder.build());
  }
  return git;
}
```

Note that exception handling was left out in order to focus on the actual purpose of the snippets.

`setMustExist` doesn't help with creating a repository *on demand*. It only causes `build()`to raise a `RepositoryNotFoundException` if no repository can be found at the specified location.

`Repository` represents the repository itself whereas `Git` serves as a factory to create *commands* which operate on the repository that it wraps. Next to the *factory methods* there is `close()`, which simply delegates to `Repository.close()`.

A Repository maintains a use counter that is decremented by `close()`. You can continue to use a repository after it was closed (through Git or the Repository's own methods) but it will be re-opened if necessary. To avoid leaking file handles you should not use a repository after it was closed.

An in-depth discussion of of how to access and initialize repositories with JGit can be found

here: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/09/22/access-git-repository-with-jgit/ and

here: http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/05/06/jgit-initialize-repository/

Comment: Excellent! will test it ASAP. So if I want to keep this Git object the Repository stays open and I should close it on exiting (I bet Git does not implement Autoclosable) and this will close the Repository too ? My comment meant that one could call the commands on the repo object (no repo no command). Git is for porcelain but still...

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D  I tried to clarify your questions within the answer. HTH

Comment: Figured this out - " but it will be re-opened if necessary" - lol. Have a look at my answer for what I ended up doing - gitDirectory.getParentFile() should be gitDirectory for my purposes

Comment: +1 for the codeaffine links that mention `Git git = Git.open(new F‌ile("/path/to/repo/.git"))` as a way to completely avoid all of the fluff above, _**if**_ you're able to clone the repositories by hand before your code needs them.

Answer (score 1):

After  Rüdiger Herrmann's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654229/281545)

```java
public static Git open(Path p) throws GitterException {
    // default LinkOption is follow links
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(p);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new GitterException("Directory " + p + " can't be created", e);
    }
    RepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new RepositoryBuilder();
    if (!isRepo(p, repositoryBuilder)) {
        LOGGER.debug(p.toAbsolutePath() + " is not a git repository.");
        try {
            return Git.init().setDirectory(p.toFile()).call();
        } catch (GitAPIException e) {
            throw new GitterException("Failed to create Git repository at "
                + p, e);
        }
    }
    try {
        return new Git(repositoryBuilder.build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new GitterException(
            "Failed to create Repository instance at " + p, e);
    }
}

static boolean isRepo(Path p, RepositoryBuilder rb)
        throws GitterException {
    if (!Files.isDirectory(p))
        throw new GitterException(p + " can't be resolved to a directory");
    final File directory = p.toFile();
    rb.addCeilingDirectory(directory); // for find() below
    // the docs say "Add a ceiling directory to the search limit list" which
    // means in plain english that it will search up to this directory,
    // which happens to be our directory, so it will only search there
    rb.findGitDir(directory); // find **and** add it to the builder
    return rb.getGitDir() != null;
}
```